# Barra de progresso contando de 0 até widht definido

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tenho uma barra de progresso e estou usando Keyframe

```css
@keyframes animaUm{
    0% { width: 0%; }
    
    100% { width: 25%}
    
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">25%</div>
</div>
```

Está funcionando perfeitamente, mas gostaria de inserir contador do progresso abaixo. Por exemplo: 1 de 10 % até chegar no tamanho do meu widht.

Comment: O valor máximo é 100%, 25% ou 10%?

Comment: Na verdade eu tenho 3 barras de progresso, cada uma eu coloquei um valor máximo, uma de 25%, outra de 50% e outra de 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De uma forma simples mas praticamente inviável:

```css
@keyframes progress-content {
  0% {
    content: '0 de 100%';
  }
  10% {
    content: '10 de 100%';
  }
  20% {
    content: '20 de 100%';
  }
  30% {
    content: '30 de 100%';
  }
  40% {
    content: '40 de 100%';
  }
  50% {
    content: '50 de 100%';
  }
  60% {
    content: '60 de 100%';
  }
  70% {
    content: '70 de 100%';
  }
  80% {
    content: '80 de 100%';
  }
  90% {
    content: '90 de 100%';
  }
  100% {
    content: '100 de 100%';
  }
}
@keyframes progress-bar {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%
  }
}

body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: orange;
  animation: progress-bar 1s linear
}
.progress::after {
  content: '100 de 100%';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 24px;
  animation: progress-content 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress"></div>
```

Uso o pseudo elemento `::after` para definir o conteúdo `X de 100%` e uso a animação para determinar o valor de X, mas apenas coloquei de 10 em 10, porque colocar de 1 em 1 é praticamente inviável

Usando JS:

```js
const progressBar = document.querySelector('.progress');

setTimeout(function increment() {
  let valuenow = Number.parseInt(progressBar.getAttribute('aria-valuenow'));

  if (valuenow < Number.parseInt(progressBar.getAttribute('aria-valuemax'))) {
    valuenow++;
    progressBar.setAttribute('aria-valuenow', valuenow);
    progressBar.style.width = valuenow+'%';
    setTimeout(increment, 500);
  }
}, 500)
```

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: orange;
}
.progress::after {
  content: attr(aria-valuenow);
  position: absolute;
  width: 45vw;
  height: 24px;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 24px;
}
.progress::before {
  content: 'de 100%';
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(55vw - 6px);
  height: 24px;
  left: 45vw;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding-left: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
```

O JS incrementa o atributo `aria-valuenow` que define o progresso com o `::after`  e o `::before` adiciona o valor máximo ("de 100%").